# How to teach neural network to get meaning similarity measure for 2 texts

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, cosine-similarity

I have an NLP task: there are database with 2 bunch of texts (50000 strings)

1) customer complaints (i.e. "i have a problem with authorization system ...")

2) answers to this complaints (i.e. "Go to pass recovery and reset it...")

The task is to get top 5 answers from database for every given complaint.

Why: to help manager look at the past answers and not to combine completely new answer. He see answers and acknowledged how usually these kind of question answered.

The problem here is that i cannot use simple Tf-Idf, because similarity measure not in terms of words, but in meaning (Gensim https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut3.html i think is not appropriate). So it is usual case that answer and question texts have 0 common words.

I use Python, Tensorflow, keras
Please provide some article or blog post corresponding problem